# Digest authentication using ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar in android

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I want to implement the digest authentication on ksoap 2 library in
 android.

My code::

```
try {

        ResponseVector = null;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Wsdl_Target_NameSpace,
               Method_Name);
        for (int i = 0; i < Property_Key.length; i++) {
           request.addProperty(Property_Key[i], Property_Value[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("input::" + request);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                 SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = null;
        SSLConnection.allowAllSSL();

        androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Url_location);


        List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();


        String HA1=convertPassMd5("abhishek:realm:123456");
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(Url_location);
        String uri=Method_Name+":"+myUri;
        String HA2=convertPassMd5(uri);
        String reponse=HA1+":nonce:"+HA2;
        String reponse1=convertPassMd5(reponse);
        headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Digest  " + reponse1));


            androidHttpTransport.call(Soap_Action,envelope,headerList);
        SoapObject results = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
        Vector response = (Vector)envelope.getResponse();
        ResponseVector =response;
        System.out.println("output::"+ResponseVector);


    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {


    } catch (SoapFault e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {


    }
```

> error log

```
com.piron.flexiguru.frontend D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-24 10:08:10.650  11643-11646/com.xyz.frontend D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 174K, 4% free 6828K/7047K, paused 3ms+2ms
04-24 10:08:10.790  11643-11664/com.xyz.frontend I/System.out﹕ input::boardlist{name=amit; }
04-24 10:08:10.830  11643-11664/com.xyz.frontend I/System.out﹕ headerList:[org.ksoap2.HeaderProperty@41100b70]
04-24 10:08:10.860  11643-11664/com.xyz.frontend I/System.out﹕ request:null
04-24 10:08:10.860  11643-11664/com.xyz.frontend I/System.out﹕ response:null
04-24 10:08:10.920  11643-11643/com.xyz.frontend D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
04-24 10:08:10.960  11643-11664/com.xyz.frontend I/System.out﹕ pull
04-24 10:08:10.960  11643-11664/com.xyz.frontend W/System.err﹕ org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41152358)
04-24 10:08:10.960  11643-11664/com.xyz.frontend W/System.err﹕ at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2035)
04-24 10:08:10.960  11643-11664/com.xyz.frontend W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:126)
04-24 10:08:10.960  11643-11664/com.xyz.frontend W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:96)
04-24 10:08:10.960  11643-11664/com.xyz.frontend W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:189)
04-24 10:08:10.970  11643-11664/com.xyz.frontend W/System.err﹕ at com.xyz.tools.Parssarwithsecure.run(Parssarwithsecure.java:155)
04-24 10:08:10.970  11643-11643/com.xyz.frontend D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
04-24 10:08:11.050  11643-11643/com.xyz.frontend D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
04-24 10:08:11.190  11643-11643/com.xyz.frontend D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-24 10:08:11.360  11643-11646/com.xyz.frontend D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 237K, 5% free 7024K/7367K, paused 4ms+1ms
04-24 10:10:08.660  11643-11643/com.xyz.frontend D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-24 10:10:13.510  11829-11833/com.xyz.frontend D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 166K, 4% free 6835K/7047K, paused 3ms+2ms
```

Comment: please Any help Sree

Comment: Edit your question and tell us what is the issue you are facing with you logcat.

Comment: I want to implement the digest authentication with soap api any help

Comment: can you able to post your logcat please

Comment: i think this may be the issue with the KSOP lib version try with a old KSOP version and read this http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=35